# Make a button to show contents which are hidden

Tags: html, button

I would like to make a button in html (like the "next step" button of [this](http://mathigon.org/active/graphs-and-networks#introduction) page). I want the hidden content to be shown whenever it is clicked. Someone please guide me how can I do this.

Comment: Got some code that you've tried?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Unfortunately a link to your website will not help anyone; if and when your problem is fixed, your link here will no longer represent the problem you're describing and your question will be redundant. For that reason we ask that you please place the relevant code within the question itself so that it will help future users.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put all the div container and make height:0; overflow hidden by default, and on click of button make height:auto for the container and add class "active" and check for condition if not container has class active then add class "active" to container

```
div#container {
  height:0;
  overflow:hidden;
}
div#container.active
 {
   height:auto;
   overflow:auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

HTML:

```
<input type="button" onclick="javascript:toggle()" value="Toggle visibility">
<div id="showhide" style="display: block">
    This text can be shown or hidden
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
  window.toggle = function() { 
    // get the Div 
    var myDiv = document.getElementById('showhide');

    // now toggle the visibility, depending on current state
    if (myDiv.style.display == 'block') { 
      // Div is visible. hide it
      myDiv.style.display = 'none';
    } else { 
      // Div is hidden. show it 
      myDiv.style.display = 'block';
    }
  }
```

Here's an example:

http://jsfiddle.net/2njLvf5p/